# What is the difference between ASP.NET vNext and ASP.NET 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I noticed that `MSDN` as well as the main `ASP.NET` [website](http://www.asp.net/vnext) uses these names interchangeably so I consider them having the same meanings. My original guess is that ASP.NET 5 can be easily confused with `ASP.NET MVC 5` so the Microsoft team decided to give it another name, something more unique. That was how `vNext` was originated. Am I close to my assumption? Is there a significant difference between ASP.NET `vNext` and `ASP.NET 5`.

Comment: `vNext` was the temporary name. The official name is now `asp.net 5`.

Comment: Also please add ASP.Net Core to your description, which is also same as vNext and ASP.Net 5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're the same thing. `ASP.NET vNext` was just the code word they used to describe `ASP.NET 5` before they decided on calling it `ASP.NET 5`. They're not supposed to say `vNext` anymore, any new documentation should refer to it as `ASP.NET 5`. Of course, since a lot of documentation already exists referring to it as `vNext`, we'll still be seeing it for quite a while.

It has nothing to do with the version number of MVC or even the .NET Framework.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It all makes sense now.

Comment: @Red - Even `ASP.NET 5` is also dead now. `ASP.NET 5` is now `ASP .NET Core 1.0`. Have a look [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx)